# The collection has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-online

I am getting all external users for the site collection using below pnp powershell. It runs perfectly for some site collections.

```
$connection =  Connect-PnPOnline -Url $siteurl -Tenant $TenantID -ClientId $AppID -Thumbprint $Thumbprint -ReturnConnection -WarningAction SilentlyContinue  
write-output "Established connection "  

$ctx = Get-PnPContext
$allusers =  Get-PnPUser -Connection $connection  | Where{$_.LoginName -like "_*#ext#*" -or $.LoginName -like "*urn:spo:guest*"}
```

But, I need to iterate over 600 000 site collections and for that I am calling 25 instances of the runbook at a time.
On doing so, for some site collections , it gives below error

> The collection has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly requested

on the get-pnpuser line and sometime during creating connection.
Not sure what is causing this.

[image: Error]

Comment: Please use universal measurements instead of local words like *lakh*. Not everyone understands them.